# Why is setcookie returning null?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

The `var_dump($cookie_set)` call says `NULL` for the following code.

```
// set cookie with token
$cookie_set = setcookie('login_perma', $token, array(
    'expires' => time()+1000*24*60*60
    , 'secure' => true
    , 'httponly' => true
    , 'samesite' => 'Lax'
));
var_dump($cookie_set);
```

Php.net reference says only true/false will be returned:

> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return TRUE.

So why is null returned and how can I fix it?

Comment: In any which case, a cookie will never be TRUE on initial pageload. Cookies only take effect when a page is reloaded.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner setcookie will return true if successful. You are probably talking about reading the $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 1):

**According to [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) in php documentation**
You can use it like :

```
$cookie_set = setcookie(
    'login_perma',// name
    $token,// value
    time()+1000*24*60*60,// expires
    null,// path (optional)
    null,// domain (optional)
    true,// secure
    true,// httponly
));
```

or

```
$cookie_set = setcookie(
    'login_perma',// name
    $token,// value
    null,// expires
    null,// path
    null,// domain
    null,// secure
    null,// httponly
    array(// options
        'expires' => time()+1000*24*60*60,
        'secure' => true,
        'httponly' => true,
        'samesite' => 'Lax'
    )
);
```

then

```
var_dump($cookie_set);
```

Answer (score -1):

The options array parameter was introduced in PHP 7.3. If one is trying to use it in a prior version the call will return null.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The manual has no mention of setcookie returning null.

Comment: But it does say that you cannot use the options array until PHP7.3